# Syncing 2 Different Installations

Tags: wordpress

I Would like to know the technology Facebook uses to sync their desktop and mobile versions.

I'm trying to sync two different installations of Wordpress (desktop and mobile) and only want the users and contents or post to sync to each other. Any suggestions? I'm thinking if there is already such a service or plugin there will be no need to start building it from scratch just for our need.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean under sync desktop and mobile installation? Do you have two separate websites that you want to merge data?

Comment: Yes. 1 Desktop version and 1 mobile version. But want to be syncing data.